# Python dict append is overwriting previous key:value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Firstly python 2.7.11

Overview, I'm gathering the directory names in a given path and passing them into a subprocess cmd. From that subprocess I'm iterating over the output line by line, the directory name is the key and the subprocess.stdout is the value.

What I need is to keep the key the same but save the unique values and add them to a dict so I can write to a csv later.

Snip it of code showing 2 methods I have already tried (one is commented out). Both overwrite the existing key:value in the dict.

```
data = []
for dname in listdir(path):
    header = dname
    if isfile:
        entrydict = dict()
        cmd = "ct lsh -fmt \"%u \\n\" -since 01-Oct-2015 -all " + dname
        # output of cmd is "name \r\n"
        p1 = subp.Popen(cmd, stdout=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.PIPE)
        usr = []
        for name in iter(p1.stdout.readline, ''):
            if name.rstrip() not in usr:
                usr.append(name.rstrip())
            else:
                entrydict[header] = usr

        for n in usr:
            entrydict[header] = n
            data.append(entrydict)
```

Thanks!

Comment: A dictionary can only take one unique at a time. So you can't assign all your values to key `header`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could collect all of the unique values as a list like `names = ['f0', 'f1', 'f2']` and then assign it to your dict with a `header` as a key like

```
entrydict[header] = names
```

Just make sure that all of `header` are different.